# jQuery datepicker issue when used on a Bootstrap prepended/appended input

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-ui-datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-2

In Firefox when clicking on the input field the datepicker doesn't show. No issues in Chrome or IE.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input id="start_date" name="start_date" class="date_field" type="text">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$('.date_field').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    minDate: 0
});
```

Libraries and versions:

- jQuery 1.7.1
- jQuery UI 1.9.2
- Bootstrap 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. I guess it was a CSS issue all along. Change the `position` property of the input field from `relative` to `static`.

```
.input-append input { position: static; }
```

Hopefully this helps other poor souls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the right order in your html?

i got a preview down below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

And you need to take a look at the API documentation.
Because it looks like you have a syntax error for the `minDate` variable.
It have to look somewhere like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1)
});
```

Comment: No syntax errors present. `minDate` works fine set to `0`. And I'm not sure you understand my issue. I need my datepicker to work with my HTML, changing it is not an option. The issue weirdly only comes up in Firefox.